# Serilog Won't Override Minimum Level For ILogger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I can't seem to get Serilog to override the minimum level settings for this IHostedService class I have.

This is my program.cs

```cs
// ...

LoggerConfiguration CreateLogConfig()
{
    var minLevel = Enum.Parse<LogEventLevel>(config["ApplicationLogging:MinimumLevel"]);

    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()

    // Set up global min level filters.
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("StartupCheck", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .MinimumLevel.Is(minLevel)

    // ...

    return logger;
}

// ...
```

Then I have a file called StartupCheck.cs which looks like this:

```cs
public class StartupCheck : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<StartupCheck> logger;
    //  ...

    public StartupCheck(ILogger<StartupCheck> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"Build Number: { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version }");

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

When the minimum level is set to Information, all the information logs, but if it's set to anything higher, then I don't see anything from this class even though I know it's running.

From Googling, I know it's something about the source context, but I can't figure out what the auto-generated source context is. I've made several attempts to not avail. my example code has the class name, but I've also tried the full namespace and part of the namespace. I've also tried getting the namespace via reflection and that didn't work either. I've tried implementing ILogger and changing the logger creation line to `factory.CreateLogger("StartupCheck");` but that didn't seem to do anything.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Would you mind going into detail about what you mean with "higher" when it comes to the logging level?

Comment: Like if I set the minimum level to Error, I wouldn't see anything because the log level is information in that class. What should happen is that I should see the information level logging from that class because it has an override on it saying that the minimum level for it is information.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `Override()` is namespace-qualified, so, if you class is `MyApp.StartupCheck`, you need to include that full string in the override, not just the class name.

Comment: Might be useful to update your question with all the details to make it representative of your real code, including the rest of the Serilog config, and how you're connecting it up to ASP.NET Core; the problem doesn't seem to be in the fragment you've posted.